# My code with in function does not perform the task but does the same while out of it?

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

Here's my code where I am flipping a bit, crossing over two lists and selecting random elements of lists:

```
def selRandom(individuals, k):
    return [random.choice(individuals) for i in range(k)]

def cxOnePoint(ind1, ind2):

    size = min(len(ind1), len(ind2))
    cxpoint = random.randint(1, size - 1)
    ind1[cxpoint:], ind2[cxpoint:] = ind2[cxpoint:], ind1[cxpoint:]

    return ind1, ind2

def mutFlipBit(individual, indpb):

    for i in range(len(individual)):
        if random.random() < indpb:
            individual[i] = type(individual[i])(not individual[i])

    return individual,




def operators(selection, crossover, mutation, parent, k, indvpb):

    select = ['randomSelection']
    cx = ['OnePoint']
    mutate = ['flipBitMutate']


    if selection not in select:
        return "invalid"

    else:

        if selection == 'randomSelection':
            (parent) = selRandom(parent, k)

    if crossover not in cx:
        return "invalid"

    else:
        if crossover == 'OnePoint':
            ind = cxOnePoint(parent[0], parent[1])

    if mutation not in mutate:
        return "not valid"
    else:
        if mutation == 'flipBitMutate':
            mutatedIndvidual = mutFlipBit(ind[0], indvpb)


    return parent, ind, mutatedIndvidual
```

I run this to execute the code:

```
indv = ([1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1],[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0],[0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1])
selection = 'randomSelection'
crossover = 'OnePoint'
mutation = 'flipBitMutate'
selected_parent, ind, mutatedIndvidual = operators(selection = selection , crossover = crossover, mutation = mutation, parent = indv, k = 3, indvpb = 0.1 )
print("Parents:\n",indv)
print("Selected parent to reproduce:\n",selected_parent)
print("Crossover offsprings:\n",ind)
print("Mutated offsprings",mutatedIndvidual)
```

And get the result:

```
Parents:
 ([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])
Selected parent to reproduce:
 [[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
Crossover offsprings:
 ([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1])
Mutated offsprings ([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],)
```

So the code is executing but is not functioning. It randomely selects from the tuple and then it does not crossovers (mixes the bits from two lists) or flips the bits. If I test run the code separately (out of the operator method) it works:

```
a = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
b = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] 
c = [1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1]
d= (a,b,c)
print("selecting randomely:\n",selRandom(d,1))
print("TESTING CROSSOVER\n", cxOnePoint(a,b))
print("Mutate:\n",mutFlipBit(a,0.4))
```

and got the proper result:

```
selecting randomely:
 [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
TESTING CROSSOVER
 ([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
Mutate:
 ([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],)
```

What is the logical mistake that I am making here?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried debugging your program step-by-step ? To test, try removing the random selection, hard-code the parents and see if the result are the same as the one you predicted.

Comment: @Thomas Weller where is find in the code? Please give the traceback.

Comment: @Alexandre Marc I have tried a lot of things and still I am unable to solve it

Comment: @Thomas Weller I will do so

Comment: @Thomas Weller I deeply apologise this should be ind and I don't know how did I put before ind. Please don't mind this and help me out.

Comment: @ Thomas bad indentation is just because of the copy pasting from the IDE

Comment: Your `cxOnePoint()` and `mutFlipBit()` functions are *modifying the original lists*.  When you print out the results at the end, the parent lists are shown with the modifications applied, so it looks like nothing changed.

Comment: @jasonharper but they work fine separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

1. I have assigned original lists in the `mutFlipBit()` and `cxOnePoint` and I changed my 'mutFlipBit()' to:

   ```
    def mutation(individual, indp):
        return [not ind if random.random() < indp else ind for ind in individual]
   ```

This worked for me